# LEGO monorail train can't climb slope

Tags: repair, monorail

Just reopened the monorail set for my son to play with. Motor still works but it grinds and can't cope with pushing up the incline to the upper level on either slope.

Looks very slightly worn but nothing big. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Sarah and welcome to Bricks.SE! By "grinds" do you mean the motor, its shaft and the attached gear are all turning, but the gear slips on the rail, or that the motor is struggling to get the shaft and the gear to turn? Can you please edit your question to incorporate this information? Meanwhile, take a look at the [tour] and the [help] pages to learn more about the community here and how things work on this site. Play well!